# How do I check if the URL is being served from AMP Cache or not?

Tags: python, caching, amp-html, user-agent

I am using requests (python) with :

```
Mobile User Agent - Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.2; GT-I9505 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.59 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

This is an AMP URL -  `https://www.whats-on-netflix.com/news/harry-potter-movies-netflix-2020/amp/`

The response.header is:

```
{‘Date’: ‘Wed, 20 Jan 2021 03:20:36 GMT’, ‘Content-Type’: ‘text/html; charset=UTF-8’, ‘Transfer-Encoding’: ‘chunked’, ‘Connection’: ‘keep-alive’, ‘Set-Cookie’: ‘__cfduid=d7e443a8d90cded562959a8767b6aab931611112836; expires=Fri, 19-Feb-21 03:20:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.whats-on-netflix.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure’, ‘Last-Modified’: ‘Tue, 19 Jan 2021 21:12:03 GMT’, ‘Cache-Control’: ‘public, max-age=7776000’, ‘Expires’: ‘Tue, 20 Apr 2021 03:20:36 GMT’, ‘Vary’: ‘Accept-Encoding,User-Agent,Accept-Encoding’, ‘CF-Cache-Status’: ‘DYNAMIC’, ‘cf-request-id’: ’07bf6804390000dca13096e000000001′, ‘Expect-CT’: ‘max-age=604800, report-uri=”https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct”&#8216;, ‘Report-To’: ‘{“endpoints”:[{“url”:”https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report?s=EBLDIer3oL87%2FzpNM0LSs0%2Fv7p3IdQLyxy%2Fn19V%2B1loHbRRpKrY33jbQPojeGf%2BVE84VzHXtbL%2FseQ3Y9YpX8X4j2qpljJQgz6mVTv%2BeO05BmgVP7xBLEFo%3D”}],”group”:”cf-nel”,”max_age”:604800}’, ‘NEL’: ‘{“report_to”:”cf-nel”,”max_age”:604800}’, ‘Strict-Transport-Security’: ‘max-age=0; preload’, ‘X-Content-Type-Options’: ‘nosniff’, ‘Server’: ‘cloudflare’, ‘CF-RAY’: ‘6145a919fbd4dca1-MAA’, ‘Content-Encoding’: ‘gzip’}
```

**This is a non-AMP URL from the same site - https://www.whats-on-netflix.com/whats-new/**

The response.header output is:

```
{‘Date’: ‘Wed, 20 Jan 2021 03:22:58 GMT’, ‘Content-Type’: ‘text/html; charset=UTF-8’, ‘Transfer-Encoding’: ‘chunked’, ‘Connection’: ‘keep-alive’, ‘Set-Cookie’: ‘__cfduid=df0951d84755de428221422eb1ac491631611112978; expires=Fri, 19-Feb-21 03:22:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.whats-on-netflix.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure’, ‘Last-Modified’: ‘Tue, 19 Jan 2021 16:37:34 GMT’, ‘Cache-Control’: ‘public, max-age=7776000’, ‘Expires’: ‘Tue, 20 Apr 2021 03:22:58 GMT’, ‘Vary’: ‘Accept-Encoding,User-Agent,Accept-Encoding’, ‘CF-Cache-Status’: ‘DYNAMIC’, ‘cf-request-id’: ’07bf6a2fff0000df538da69000000001′, ‘Expect-CT’: ‘max-age=604800, report-uri=”https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct”&#8216;, ‘Report-To’: ‘{“endpoints”:[{“url”:”https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report?s=QKFl%2FTQTZvtieurNFr6Krrkc%2BJXUFNPUiMc7ikJQGvUUFgpj%2FQ6SBOXZSiksAcRCXmowGPDJyeLNBDEw%2F4eBOo2pnWYHoF0scayNWXHEHpU0xOi%2Bv1CB0So%3D”}],”group”:”cf-nel”,”max_age”:604800}’, ‘NEL’: ‘{“max_age”:604800,”report_to”:”cf-nel”}’, ‘Strict-Transport-Security’: ‘max-age=0; preload’, ‘X-Content-Type-Options’: ‘nosniff’, ‘Server’: ‘cloudflare’, ‘CF-RAY’: ‘6145ac933f36df53-BOM’, ‘Content-Encoding’: ‘gzip’}
```

---

It looks the same, so how do I differentiate if the URL is being served from AMP cache or not?

**Objective: If the URL is not being served from AMP Cache, I would use requests to force cache the URL.**
**I am currently using LiteSpeed Cache and I use a similar method by checking if substring "'X-LiteSpeed-Cache': 'hit'" is there in response header or not?**

Comment: I don't understand usually AMP cache URL is different and if it's not cached it will redirect to the original URL

Usually, Cache-control is private for AMP cache

eg: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.republicworld.com/amp/entertainment-news/hollywood-news/is-harry-potter-coming-to-netflix-find-out-if-all-8-movies-will-be-arriving-in-november.html

eg: https://www-whats--on--netflix-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.whats-on-netflix.com/whats-new/whats-new-on-netflix-top-10s-january-22nd-2021/amp/